# Use variables in JQuery .css() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to set an image's `left` and `right` values randomly using JQuery by doing the following:

```
var sides = ["left", "right"]
var currentSide = sides[Math.floor(Math.random() * sides.length)];
$("#"+currentImage).css({currentSide : "80px"});
```

So i have an array that contains either 'left' or 'right' which gets randomly selected and the CSS of the element gets set to either `right: "80px";` or `left: 80px;`

But, its not working. When I go and set it statically e.g. `$("#"+currentImage).css({"left" : "80px"});` then it works fine, so it's just passing variables to the `.css()` function that's making this break.

Any ideas?

Comment: why not `$("#"+currentImage).css( currentSide , "80px" );`  [doc](http://api.jquery.com/css/)?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to create an object with a dynamic key, in that case you need to use bracket notation. In your case you are creating an object with key `currentSide` not `left/right`.

You can use

```
$("#"+currentImage).css(currentSide, "80px");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer this a bit more generally so you don't run into this type of problem in the future, with other applications that may not have an alternate syntax like `$().css()` does. Using this method you can also assign multiple styles using a single `.css()` call.

```
var sides = ["left", "right"]
var currentSide = sides[Math.floor(Math.random() * sides.length)];
var styles = {};
styles[currentSide] = "80px";
$("#"+currentImage).css(styles);
```